# Help with a proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm studying this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Steps_in_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&redir_esc=y) and I'm having troubles with the following proof

Why the red line implies the blue one?

I'm almost sure that would be a silly thing, I'm sorry if it really is.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: The fact that two distinct maximal ideals are coprime should probably be extracted from all this stuff about PIDs.

Answer (score 4):

by definition of maximal ideal. there are no ideals properly containing it not equal to the whole ring

Comment: To expand on @mm-aops' reply, the sum of two ideals is an ideal, so $R_{p_i} + R_{p_j}$ is an ideal. Here's a proof: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Ideals_is_Ideal

Comment: right, should've probably mentioned that, thanks

Comment: yes, of course, thanks a lot! I knew it was a silly thing.